# Autolayout removes UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, constraints

I am trying to add shadow around a uiview, trying to use this code https://github.com/benboecker/ShadowView/blob/master/ShadowView/ShadowView.swift

View is added in storyboard and not managing properties programmatically

It works perfectly when frame is same as in storyboard and NO autolayout is applied.

[image]

the moment I add any constraint that moves the frame with autolayouts, looks like `self.layer.shadowPath` is removed and calling  `layoutSubviews()` or `setNeedsLayout()` or `layoutIfNeeded()` doesnt help at all.

Add an autolayout constraint
[image]

Final version doesnt have the shadow anymore because uiview frame is changed.

[image]

I tried calling layout after viewdidappear too, didnt help .

```
 @IBOutlet weak var shadowView: ShadowView!
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.shadowView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Are you adding constraints that pin the edges of your view to the edges of its superview?

Comment: Yes, shadowView to self-view any constraints that move the frame of the shadowView makes the shadow disappear

Comment: The shadow is *outside* the frame of the view. Set your Leading constraint to a value such as 32, and see if the shadow shows up on the left.

Comment: `Shadow View.leading = leadingMargin + 30` no it doesnt.

Comment: You must be doing something else... I just grabbed that ShadowView.swift you linked to, and it works just fine with constraints. Try setting the background color of your ShadowView to yellow, then post a screen-shot of the result.

Comment: you are right, I think shadowView frame is moving out of visible frame so I cant see the shadow

Comment: This is something out of subject, how do you add a line below password or Email text field?